# Don't know what I’m looking for regarding removable HDDs?

Tags: backup, external-hard-drive, removable

Ok all. So I’m a gamer and haven’t built my own system since the 90s. I’ve always had a backup USB HDD in case I run into issues and have to format. I’m looking to have a bay for a HDD that I can remove and put in a different one, kind of like unplugging a external HDD and plugging in a new one.

Currently two of my bays are for optical drives (although one isn’t showing in my list below). I don't know if what I’m looking for even exists or if it has to do with some server tech but I am looking for something that’s compatible with [my system](https://pcpartpicker.com/user/Wizardhood2003/saved/82VMZL).

Comment: If you just have an occasional need to plug in a hard drive one of the new [USB Hard drive Docks](https://www.amazon.com/Sabrent-External-Docking-Station-DS-UBLK/dp/B00IKAQ538) work well and can just sit on your desk.

Answer (score 14):

Sounds like what you are after is a hot-swap bay.

They make different flavors depending on if you want to use 3.5 inch drives or 2.5 inch drives. Here is one for two 2.5 inch drives that will fit in the 5.25 inch standard optical drive bay.
[image: https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-2-5-Inch-Trayless-Backplane-HSB220SAT25B]

If you want one for 3.5 inch drives, they are available too.

Comment: Just make sure that the HD is protected from static, water, and physical knocks.  USB enclosures usually do the job well, but if you have a safe place for the HD, the hot swap bay is fine.  There are also hard drive docks, which are like hot swap bays in a standalone USB device.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage you may be able to find enclosed trays that give all around protection.  We had them for 3.5" drives at my previous job (drives were being pulled and locked in a safe nightly so they needed to be well protected); but they were bought something like a decade ago and I couldn't find an example quickly today.

Comment: @DanNeely I guess you mean something with a caddy for the HDD which also has data and power connectors, so that the ones on the HDD don't wear out. No, I can't find them either.

Comment: @AndrewMorton yes.  They were fully enclosed caddies that held drives similarly to USB enclosures, but had (proprietary?) connectors to plug into the bay unit instead of USB and DC power plugs on the back.

Comment: @DanNeely I've found one example: [Startech hot-swap-hard-drive-bay-usb-enclosure](https://www.startech.com/uk/HDD/Mobile-Racks/hot-swap-hard-drive-bay-usb-enclosure~S251BU31REM). Must now try to resist gadget purchase.

Comment: Nice find.  The USB dual use mode puts that one up on the enclosures used at my last job, OTOH the use of a berg power connector on the back of the bay unit itself is pure Startech WTFery.

Comment: The photo appears to depict a device that fits in a 3.5" floppy bay, not the stated 5.25" optical drive bay.

Comment: I've used removable drive bays (for 5.25" HDD drives). The ones I'm familiar with have simple connectors built in to the mating parts. I wouldn't trust such a setup for  an actual "hot" swap; I always did swaps with the machine powered down. If you want to do hot swaps, make sure the device is advertised for that capability (power/ground and signal connections should mate progressively)

Comment: @Zenilogix I wondered, too, whether hot-swappability (is that a word!?) is actually needed for the OP. How would it work anyway?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I've seen hot-swappable circuit boards (for a telephony system). The boards had their edge connectors arranged such that certain conductors mated first on insert, de-mated last on removal, creating an inherent two (or perhaps three) step connection/disconnection. This allowed for the whole system to be continuously powered while allowing individual cards to be inserted or removed at any time for servicing or upgrade. One could imagine something along similar lines for a HDD, just not sure how it would be done "right". FWIW I think USB employs this principle.

Answer (score 4):

As noted by in another answer to this question, what you are (likely) looking for is called a "*hot swap(pable) hard drive bay*".

Hot swapping is intended to allow replacement of failed hard drivers without powering off a device. As a consequence, hot swapping a hard drives often mean being able to remove it from the front of the machine. There are inserts that allow for this via standard-sized drive bays (i.e. the hard drive sits in a tray/cage inside this bay).

Comment: Effectively a feature of SOHO NAS for a while (Sata). It helps to know which disk has failed if this is for RAID6 too.